# Is it possible to write this jquery code shorter? (beginner)

Tags: jquery

This is my first time i ask something on stackoverflow so forgive me if i do anything wrong. I am also new to jquery but through reading and tutorials i managed to create a working example.

The code below is what i created. The meaning of this is that i have three lists with draggable requirements and three placeholders where the requirements can be dropped. The idea is that placeholder 1 is only accepting items from list 1, placeholder 2 only from list 2 and placeholder 3 from list 3. When a requirement is dragged the placeholder will be highlighted so the user knows where it can be dropped.

So now for the question: Is there a way to crop this code? I have the feeling this is not the best way, it is three time the same code with only two words that are changing. As i learned from the tutorials: Never write things two times.

Also another question: Is it possible when the requirements are dropped in the placeholders to create a line between it? I would like the user to click on one placeholder and click on the other placeholder to draw a connection. I already saw a lot of examples with html5 canvas and jsPlumb but i don't need all that functionalities. Only one line between the placeholders when clicked.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#requirements" ).accordion();
    $( "#requirements ul li" ).draggable({ 
    appendTo: "body", 
    helper: "clone" 
});

$( ".row1 .placeholder" ).droppable({ //makes row1 .placeholder a droppable area
     accept: "#requirements .row1 li ", 
     activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
     drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
        $this.droppable('disable').addClass("highlighted");
     }
});

$( ".row2 .placeholder" ).droppable({ //makes row2 .placeholder a droppable area
     accept: "#requirements .row2 li ", 
     activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
     drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
        $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
        $this.droppable('disable').addClass("highlighted");
     }
});

$( ".row3 .placeholder" ).droppable({ //makes row3 .placeholder a droppable area
     accept: "#requirements .row3 li ", 
     activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
     drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
        $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
        $this.droppable('disable').addClass("highlighted");
    }    
});
```

As said i am new to jquery so good explanations are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Rob

Comment: This may be better off on Code Review. Having said that, one of the best written first questions I've ever seen on SO.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question but: make an effort to use "angular.js directives", it will remove all this ugly code that you use only to handle the HTML, and you could write the business logic code that matters to you.

Comment: Good to see first timers actually putting together well written questions and showing an understanding for the basics of what they are doing.

Comment: I suggest put all .droppable() code in a function and passing .row1,.row2 and .row3 as a parameter to that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a function that returns the object that you are reusing, inserting the row class or whatever parameter needs to change in it:

```
function getSettings(rowClass){
    var obj ={ //makes row1 .placeholder a droppable area
      accept: "#requirements "+rowClass+" li ", 
      activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
        $this.droppable('disable').addClass("highlighted");
      }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Then call it as in `$( ".row2 .placeholder" ).droppable(getSettings(".row2")`. Haven't tested it, but it should work. Changing any part that's not static to be a function parameter should be enough if the use case is the one you described.

Welcome to jQuery!

Comment: Thanks i'm going to try it!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
var rowArr = [".row1", ".row2", ".row3"];
$(rowArr).each(function(curr) {
    $(curr + " .placeholder").droppable({
        accept: "#requirements " + curr + " li",
        /*rest of the code remains the same*/
    });
});
```

Comment: `.map()` is used to "convert" each value from an array into another one. `.each()` would be the better candidate here.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction! Going to try this one too.

Comment: @s4ty It would fail if there are classes like `row-hover` also present?

Comment: well, yes it would ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about using like this:

```
    $( ".row1 .placeholder, .row2 .placeholder, .row3 .placeholder" ).droppable({ //makes row1 .placeholder a droppable area
var rowClass = [".row1",".row2", ".row3"];
$(rowClass).each(function(thisrow){
     accept: "#requirements" +  thisrow + "li ", 
         activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
         drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
            $this.droppable('disable').addClass("highlighted");
         }
});
    });
```